# how to extract animation from flash to image files and a xml describing the motion?

Tags: xml, animation, flash, export

I want to create animations in flash, and then export a sprite sheet with the sprites and a xml(or another format) with information about how to "cut" and move the sprites.

I don't know where to start, use some library for reading swf in c# or java? try to export using AS3 inside the swf?

I know others had than this kind of tool (castle crashers, super meat boy)

http://supermeatboy.blogspot.com/2009/06/i-made-something-neato.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just had a great answer to this on [Gamedev.stackexchange](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/24376/how-to-export-flash-animation-data).

Basically, check out [Grapefrukt](https://github.com/grapefrukt/grapefrukt-export).  It can build a sprite sheet out of your Flash animations or it can export the images and the movement information as XML.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good idea. My route would be to build an air app that would import an swf loaded with tweened movie clips. Instantiate and play the selected clip, and run a bitmapdata.draw() on each frame. If you knew the number of frames yould could easily do a little math to determine the total size, and precisely add the individual frame data to a sprite sheet. Then save the bitmap to your local system. Any xml could be dealt with in the same way. Create a nice gui and you'd have a really useful tool. My $.02 !

Comment: Man. The link that @Mattias posted does exactly this. That'll save a bit of work putting it all together. Still, a really good idea ;)

Comment: thanks boswoth99 but i want somthing like this http://supermeatboy.blogspot.com/2009/06/i-made-something-neato.html, dont need all the frames of the animation.